# Will a parent Window receives a WM_PAINT message if a child control covers the invalid rectangle?

Tags: c, winapi

Say I have the following Window with a Button:

[image]

If the rectangle where the Button is placed needs to be painted, will a `WM_PAINT` message only be sent to the Button or will it also be sent to the parent Window?

---

**Edit:** I mean by "needs to be painted" for example: if I minimized and restored the window, if I covered it with another window and then uncovered it (not sure if this causes a `WM_PAINT` message in Windows 7 though), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invalidate the button, you would call `InvalidateRect` passing the button's window handle. This will lead to a `WM_PAINT` message being delivered to the button. No `WM_PAINT` message is delivered to the button's parent.

In the comments you describe a scenario whereby the parent window is resized to reveal a previously hidden button. In that case both the parent and the button would be invalid, and so both would receive `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: What if I decreased the size of the Window to hide the Button and then I increased the size to re-show the Button. Will a `WM_PAINT` message also be sent to the Button alone and not to the Window?

Comment: Changing the size of a window will lead to it being repainted, irrespective of whether or not there are children

Comment: You are right. I have tested it (by minimizing and restoring the Window) and the `PAINTSTRUCT.rcPaint` rectangle had the same coordinates as the client area of the Window. So I guess that the answer to my question is that indeed two `WM_PAINT` messages are sent: one for the Button and one for the parent Window.

Comment: The answer to the question that you asked is as I wrote, I believe. The question you asked in comments is a different question.

Comment: No, my two questions are the same.

Comment: No. One question asks about invalidating the button, the other asks about resizing the top level window. At least, that's what is written.

Comment: I said in my question: "If the rectangle where the Button is placed needs to be painted", so this means that where the button is placed is also the same as where part of the Window exists.

Comment: I guess you need to define "needs to be painted". I assumed a call to InvalidateRect. Did I guess wrongly.

Comment: I meant by "needs to be painted" for example: if I minimized and restored the window, if I covered it with another window and then uncovered it (not sure if this causes a `WM_PAINT` message in Windows 7 though), etc.

Comment: I guess you need to fix the question then. Let me know when you've done so and i'll make my answer match.

Comment: When I try to edit my question, they give me a "Page Not Found" error. I will edit it later when this bug is fixed.